# Managing Remote MySQL DB using local phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

is there any way to manage a remote MySQL server using a local phpMyAdmin?
I don't think they will allow me to upload a copy of phpmyadmin through ftp. For the meantime, I've been managing the remote db through CLI and it really is a pain. I tried changing the host value in config.inc.php of phpmyadmin. I think I am able to connect to the DB but it always says "No databases".

I am certain that I have entered the correct IP address of my MySQL host and I am entering the correct username and password. But why is it showing "No Databases"?

Comment: This should be on serverfault. Make sure that the remote database allows remote connetions at all.

Comment: As long as we're posting off-topic questions, how about an off-topic answer: Why is managing the DB through the CLI a pain? Most professional DBAs aren't installing phpMyAdmin...

Comment: @Dan Even though you say that most professional DBAs are using a CLI, believe it or not I would really prefer to use a GUI. I really want my rows to show with a little pretty formatting and I really find the feature of viewing content in one click really useful. Why would I settle for a CLI if there is a GUI alternative? I really am sorry if I am not at a level that you are expecting developers to be.

Comment: @Michael-O I am able to connect to the DB through CLI and have been doing so to the present. Is the connection made by `mysql` different from what phpmyadmin is using?

Comment: Well, if you are connecting locally, phpMyAdmin uses Unix Domain Sockets, probably `mysql` does too. Remote connection uses TCP. Try `mysql` from a remote host.

Comment: Although I much prefer the CLI interface, the output from PHPMyAdmin is often much easier to read. If you do end up having to use the CLI, did you know that you can get results output in vertical format by replacing the terminating semi-colon with `\G`?  e.g.: `SELECT * FROM mytable\G`  It's not perfect, but it might help make the output easier to read.

Comment: @Dan Every tool has its own usage cases. In my opinion it's unprofessional to use the same tool for all possible purposes. In many cases it can be a time wasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else needs / wants to know I used [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually logging in, but it says no databases, this is an issue you will have to take up with the hosting provider.  It may be for security purposes that they do not allow exterior connections to the mysql databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily via phpMyAdmin. Check this wiki:

see the phpmyadmin wiki page: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.ne/pma/Config#Server.28s.29_configuration

That should be enough. Let me know if you have any problem doing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add below lines to your “config.inc.php” file in the bottom:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'HostName:port'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'userName';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';       // keep it as config
```

. You will get  “Current Server:” drop down  with both “127.0.0.1” and one what you have provided with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` cam switch between the servers.